# Android scroll layout without scrollView

Tags: android, scrollview

I have `listView` in layout, so I cannot use `ScrollView`. The question is pretty straight forward: how can I make layout scroll when soft keyboard is on or all layout is not visible?

Comment: Put your listview and ther chidren in a common linear layout and then put scroll view on top of that linear layout

Comment: Then listview doesn't scroll

Comment: Then have you tried `android:windowSoftInputMode=“adjustPan”`  ?

Comment: It should scroll.. show your xml layout.Try this Hierarchy ScrollView-->`LinearLayout`--> LinearLayout-->ListView